# Azure VM outbound IP

Tags: windows, networking, azure

Does anyone know what controls the outbound ip address of a VM in an ARM deployment? The deployment I am working on has only a single public ip which is assigned to a load balancer. Some VM's are using this public ip as their outbound ip and some are not and there does not seem to be any logic in why. Ideally I want all vm's (which are a mixture of A nd D series) to use the same outbound ip, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an internet facing load balancer using ARM and Resource Groups. All the machines you want behind the load balancer will need to share the same backend IP pool.

You can find the steps to set one up here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-arm-powershell/

Comment: For anyone that is looking for an answer to this issue, Jennel Crothers is basically right. Any VM's you want to share the same outbound IP need to be members of the same availability set as the VM's that are in the backend pool of the load balancer. As you can only have 1 availability set in the backend pool, if you need more than 1 you need more than 1 load balancer with another IP and so on, pretty painful.

Comment: what if i have a VM that do not have load balancer or static ip. can i have a fix outbound ip ?

Comment: Yes, you can now assign a static public IP address to an individual machine - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-deploy-static-pip-arm-portal